# Is there an efficient way to check for a list of files and download the ones that don't exist?

Tags: python-3.x, io

Basically what I'm trying to do is iterate through a list of filenames, check if they already exist at a given path, and download them if they do not exist using another list of download links.

It's been a while since I've touched Python and a few buddies of mine wanted an automated way to keep our mods in sync between updates. I'm sure there's a smarter way to store the links/names(such as a map) but that isn't the question at hand here. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

I have a feeling my issue may be a syntax error.

```
import requests
from os.path import exists

modsPath = os.getenv('APPDATA') + "\.minecraft\mods"
links = []
print("Grabbing Download Links...")
with open(modsPath + "\master_downloads_list.txt") as g:
    for line in g:
        if 'str' in line:
            break
        links.append(line.strip())
        print("Grabbed " + line.strip())
print("Grabbed Download Links...")
with open(modsPath + "\master_mods_list.txt") as f:
    i = -1
    for line in f:
        i = i + 1
        #Standard.
        if 'str' in line:
            break
        #If Mod already exists in filesystem, skip.
        if not(exists(modsPath + line.strip())):
            #If Mod doesn't exist in filesystem, download mod.
            url = links[i]
            dl = requests.get(url, allow_redirects = True)
            open(line.strip(), 'wb').write(dl.content)
        print("Mod " + line.strip() + " exists & is updated. Skipping.")
```

Comment: What's inefficient about it?

Comment: I should've actually explained that for some reason my code doesn't do anything when run. Isn't throwing any errors in IDLE either

Comment: To check the difference between two lists of files, you can create a `set` object containing each list, and then use [set operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set).

Comment: `if 'str' in line: break` What is that for? If `str` appears in an early line, the loops will do nothing after seeing it.

Comment: Remember that keeping files in sync is more complicated than just downloading files that don't exist. What if a file was updated? How about if I deleted a file? Would it magically keep showing up on my computer? What if multiple people updated a file? There's no need to reinvent version control when you have tools like git to do it for you (with some involvement on your part, but if you're writing mods then you can learn how to use a tool to keep sync

Comment: I never said I was writing mods, nor did I imply the necessity of full version control. This script is for a bunch of layman that barely use computers outside of gaming, so that they can double click a file and it's all ready for them.

However, I do like the idea with the set operations and will try to move the 'str' checks to the bottom of their respective loops.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] when you ask a question on Stack Overflow. A [mre] must be as minimal as you can make it, while still reproducing your problem _as seen in your question_ on a stranger's computer. Since we don't have access to those files, there's no way we can run your code without many modifications, which might obscure your original issue

Comment: Sure, if you have one server and a bunch of clients then that can work. The point about modified files and deleted files still stands though. If you want to make a proper synchronization program, you need to account for those possibilities. One way you could get around this is to create a hidden database which contains the hash of each file you want to sync, so every time you check this database you can tell which files are new, which files are to be deleted, and which files have been modified